# Evaluating a polar double integral on the semi disc

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

The integral:

$$\iint_D (x^2-y^2)\,dx\,dy$$

where $D$ is defined as:

$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2\le 1, x\ge 0\}$$

#### Context

I have solved double integrals on quarter discs but this semi disc is giving me a head ache.

Comment: I have solved double integrals on quarter discs but this semi disc is giving me a head ache.

Comment: I reformatted the question. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry the integral is $0$.

**Remark:** If you consider quarter-disks familiar, the half-disk can be broken up into two quarter-disks.

Answer (score 0):

So in polar coordinates it would be defined as:

$$0 \le r \le 1, 0 \le \theta \le \pi$$

So your double integral would be:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1 r\cos(2\theta)rdrd\theta$$

Can you solve from here?